# How to transform XML with entries of key value pairs to a HTML table?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath, xhtml

I have an multiple entities (`<data>` in my example) with key-value pairs. Every entity contains the same keys in the same order, but I don't know which and how many. How to transform this to a HTML table using XSLT, having the keys in the table headers and the values of the entities in the table rows?

```
<data>
  <entry>
     <key>id</key><value>12345</value>
  </entry>
  <entry>
     <key>price</key><value>12.45</value>
  </entry>
  <entry>
      <key>country</key><value>UK</value>
  </entry>
<data>
<data>
  <entry>
     <key>id</key><value>67890</value>
  </entry>
  <entry>
     <key>price</key><value>67.89</value>
  </entry>
  <entry>
      <key>country</key><value>DE</value>
  </entry>
<data>
```

... should become ...

```
<tr><th>id</th><th>price</th><th>country</th></tr>
<tr><td>12345</td><td>12.45</td><td>UK</td></tr>
<tr><td>67890</td><td>67.89</td><td>DE</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="//data[1]/entry">
                    <th>
                        <xsl:value-of select="key"/>
                    </th>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="//data"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="entry"/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12345</td>
    <td>12.45</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>67890</td>
    <td>67.89</td>
    <td>DE</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How do you apply the xsl to the xml ?

Comment: @sinsedrix, What do you mean?

Comment: I tried adding `<?xml-stylesheet href="data.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>` in th XML header but it doesn't generate HTML at all :(